# golang net module(LookupSRV)

Tags: go

I'm very new to golang, I have some experience with python but not on this level per say. I am creating an application that's called "digall", making it easy for a user to see active dns-records when checking a domain name.

In the application I am using `LookupSRV`, which I seem to have some issues with:

```
    func srvRecord(query string) {
        service := "sipfederationtls"
        protocol:= "tcp"
        fmt.Printf("\n[+] SRV Record(s)\n")
        //srvMap := ["sipfederationtls", "autodiscover", "VLMCS"]
        cname, addresses, err := net.LookupSRV(service, protocol, query)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("[!] This feature is currently under development, thus not ready yet.\n")
        }

        fmt.Printf("cname : %s \n", cname)

        for i := 0; i < len(addresses); i++ {
                fmt.Printf("addrs[%d].Target : %s \n", i, addresses[i].Target)
                fmt.Printf("addrs[%d].Port : %d \n", i, addresses[i].Port)
                fmt.Printf("addrs[%d].Priority : %d \n", i, addresses[i].Priority)
                fmt.Printf("addrs[%d].Weight : %d \n", i, addresses[i].Weight)
        }
}
```

As you can see the variable "service" serves as the prefix of the SRV record. My only problem is that i want to check multiple prefixes of this record, namely "sipfederationtls", "autodiscover" and "VLMCS".

What I am asking is; How to i make this function swift through these prefixes and return the ones that work? (the ones that error out will be handled by err by my fantastic error message)

I am aware that this is a noob question, and like I said I am very new to golang. I would appreciate any tips you guys could give me.

Here is the full source of the application: http://dpaste.com/3X24ZYR

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query multiple services at once using `LookupSRV` method, as you can't use `dig` for querying several services at once.

You better create a slice of the services' names:

```
services := [...]string{"service1", "service2", "service3")
```

And then iterate over it and call `LookupSRV` for each service:

```
for _, service := range services {
    cname , addrs, err := net.LookupSRV(service, "tcp", "your.domain.name")

    // error handlling
}
```

Also when iterating over the lookup result, it is better to use the `range` keyword:

```
for _, record := range addrs {
    fmt.Printf("Target: %s:%d\n", record.Target, record.Port)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to add it to my application but I keep getting errors like this:

 go run digall.go google.com
# command-line-arguments
./digall.go:54: undefined: err
./digall.go:58: undefined: cname
./digall.go:60: undefined: addresses
./digall.go:61: undefined: addresses
./digall.go:62: undefined: addresses
./digall.go:63: undefined: addresses
./digall.go:64: undefined: addresses
./digall.go:91: cannot use query[1] (type byte) as type string in argument to srvRecord

The unaltered version is here: http://dpaste.com/3X24ZYR

Comment: Please notice I've declared `cname`, `addrs` and `err` inside the loop, so they won't be available if you are trying to print their content outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I think I've figured it out. Thank you! :)